# Cannot install app update on iPad -- was already accepted in Apple's app store

Tags: ios, ipad, flash-builder

When I try to install a new .ipa on my development iPad by dragging the file to ITunes then to the iPad the icon remains dimmed and will not launch. I'm wondering if there is some new procedure I must follow now that the app has been accepted into the ITunes store. I've been assuming I could use the same certificate and distribution provisioning profile I've been using all the while but perhaps I'm wrong.
I'm developing within the Flash Builder 4.7 environment

Comment: You can't install distribution build to your iPad in this way

Comment: This is however the method I used before it was accepted. Are you suggesting I must upload it directly to the store now? I hesitate doing this without knowing the file is healthy first.

Comment: If you need to install the app from Xcode you need to use developer support or if you need to test the App Store build you need to use iTunes Beta Testing option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to submit the app to iTunes and trust it works ok. I don't know why the distribution profile won't allow testing on the device beforehand.